# nginx FastCGI-strip off the location prefix?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, web.py

I'm writing a web application in Python using web.py, spawn_fcgi and nginx.

Let's say that I have this configuration block in nginx:

```
location / {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
```

If I then access, say, `http://example.com/api/test`, then the FastCGI application receives `/api/test` as its request location. The web.py framework will use this location when determining which class to execute. For example:

```
urls = ( "/api/.*", myClass )
```

The problem comes if I need to place this script in another location on the website. For example:

```
location /app {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
```

Now, when I access `http://example.com/app/api/test`, the FastCGI application gets `/app/api/test` as its location.

It could of course be located just about anywhere: `http://example.com/sloppy_admin/My%20Web%20Pages/app/api/test` for example. :-)

I would like the app to be relocatable, as installing it on other servers may necessitate this (e.g. it has to share the server with something else). It also seems a bit hardheaded to insist that every server place it in the same "virtual subdirectory".

Right now, my workaround has been to do something like this:

```
URL_PREFIX = "/app" # the same as the nginx location parameter
urls = ( URL_PREFIX+"/api/.*",myClass )
```

The problems here are 1) this means that the script still needs to be edited per site (not necessarily horrible but at the least inconvenient) and 2) that the `URL_PREFIX` variable has to be globally accessible to the entire collection of scripts - because for example any class or function may need to access the location but it would need to not include the prefix.

I'm using custom python packages (e.g. directories containing **init**.py scripts) to simplify managing the different scripts that make up the app, but the problem is passing that URL_PREFIX parameter around. Example:

app.py:

```
from myapp import appclass
import web

URL_PREFIX = "/app" # the same as the nginx location parameter
urls = ( URL_PREFIX+"/api/.*",appclass.myClass )
app = web.application(urls,globals())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.wsgi.runwsgi = lambda func, addr=None: web.wsgi.runfcgi(func, addr)
    app.run()
```

myapp/appclass.py:

```
class myClass:
    def GET(self):
        global URL_PREFIX # this does not work!
        return URL_PREFIX
```

Is there either an nginx parameter to cause the path sent to FastCGI to be relative to the location, or a more elegant way to handle this in web.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fastcgi.conf` file should have all the configuration options you need. You might also want to look at the `fastcgi_split_path_info` directive.

[Nginx FastCGI documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html).

Comment: I have exactly this problem: @fdmillion mind telling me what exactly you set as fastcgi_split_path_info?